# Unable to run the gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

in gitlab.rb, i have put in external url like below. 
I wanted to access gitalab in the browser like
 http://ip address of my system/gitlab 
Because other applications are running in system

external_url 'http://ip address of my system/gitlab'

Can some please guide me opn the above.

Comment: Usually, you'd have a GitLab instance on its own server to reduce risk. Also, StackOverflow isn't the correct SE board for this question. Why not have your own server and point a subdomain

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main URL types you can use when setting up gitlab:

- Using a subdomain, e.g. `http://gitlab.example.com`
- Using a relative URL e.g. `http://example.com/gitlab` (this is what you are doing)

Gitlab recommends using the subdomain approach and they have made efforts to support relative URLs out of the box in recent releases but it is still not recommended.

Make sure you run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and maybe also `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` after you change the `external_url` setting.

More info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-a-relative-url-for-gitlab)